# Windows 10 keep trying to recreate a share that no longer exists

Tags: windows-10, event-log, sharing

Keep receiving warning level messages (Source: Server) in System event log:

**The server service was unable to recreate the share xyz because the directory E:\xyz no longer exists.  Please run "net share xyz /delete" to delete the share, or recreate the directory E:\xyz**.

But net share of course does not list such share (there is no such share), so there is nothing to delete.

Comment: Right click on the Start button and select Computer Management. From the left pane, expand Shared Folders and select Shares. From the right, see if you can delete your share.

Comment: Did you use Offline Folders for that Share?

Comment: Did you try running the `net share xyz /delete` command anyway (as administrator)?

Comment: 1. The Computer Management , Shared Folder Extensions shows the same shares as the "net share" command shows. In this case unfortunately the xyz share it is not listed there, nor shows up with "net share". I do not know if it was an Offline Folder that share
2. I have run the net share xyz /delete and it returned: This shared resource does not exist. And this is the true, because there is no such share

Comment: Make sure you run as administrator. Its a different userprofile and thus different shares.

Comment: Every program involved was started as administrator.

Comment: In the mean time I have found the answer and solution: Shares are listed in SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Sharesregistry key.  Source http://serverfault.com/questions/543326/how-to-remove-a-windows-share-when-the-folder-does-not-exist-anymore

Comment: What is not clear though, why windows let them there and not showing/listing them with `net share`.   And that registry key had more than this `xyz` non existent share, but for those there where no complains in the event log. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).
2. From the View menu, select the Tree and Data option.
3. Navigate to the following key:
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares
4. Select the Share that no longer exists.
5. From the Edit menu, click Delete.
6. Quit Registry Editor.
7. Shutdown and restart Windows NT.